# Using * as a primitive on Nat

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci, data-kinds

I'm currently going through Sandy Maguire's [Thinking with Types](https://thinkingwithtypes.com), and chapter 2 covers *Terms, Types and Kinds.* In it, there's an example of a simple interaction with the type-level primitives for performing arithmetic on `Nat`s.

The following session is shown to work in the book, but fails on my machine:

```
Prelude> import GHC.TypeLits
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :set -XTypeOperators
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :kind! (1 + 17) * 3

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    * Expected kind `* -> Nat -> k0', but `1 + 17' has kind `Nat'
    * In the type `(1 + 17) * 3'
```

The next example in the book works, though:

```
Prelude GHC.TypeLits> :kind! (128 `Div` 8) ^ 2
(128 `Div` 8) ^ 2 :: Nat
= 256
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with `*` also indicates a *kind*. Sandy Maguire writes that this syntax is slated for deprecation, but if it's still around, I can see how GHCi thinks I mean the *kind* `*` instead of the type-level *function* `*`.

Am I on the right track, and if so, is there some flag I can use to make the example work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect the problem has something to do with * also indicates a
>   kind.

Yes, that's the problem. It can be solved by using the [`-XNoStarIsType`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=staristype#extension-StarIsType) extension, that lets you treat `*` as just another type operator.

To refer to the kind formerly known as `*` you can import `Type` form [`Data.Kind`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html). For example, the kind of `Maybe` is `Type -> Type` and the kind of `StateT` is `Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type`.

Hopefully, at some point in the future `-XNoStarIsType` will become the default and we'll always use  `Type`.